# we want to search for an empty column and add items to that column using a vba form

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
     Dim NextEmptyCol As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("ComboBoxList")

NextEmptyCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column - 1

       Row = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
       ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value = Me.Response.Value 
       MsgBox "Column number " & NextEmptyCol & vbCr & _
"Or column letter """ & Replace(Cells(1, NextEmptyCol).Address(0, 0), 1, "") & """", _vbInformation, "The Next Empty Column is..."


End Sub
```

Comment: The title is the place where we ask the question, the details must be put in the description ... It is logical however that the description is not the one to put a block of code ....Please read : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't see a question.  Please check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question to add more information, including detail about **what you've tried so far**.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you are wanting, but I think this might point you in the right direction:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = Worksheets("ComboBoxList").Cells(1, Worksheets("ComboBoxList").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
'find the last column with data on row 1 (add 1 to this number to find the next empty column)
LastRow = Worksheets("ComboBoxList").Cells(Worksheets("ComboBoxList").Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row 
'find the last row with data on the last column
Worksheets("ComboBoxList").Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol).Value = Me.response.Value 
'add the value of Response to the next empty row in the last column (empty row is lastrow with data +1)
End Sub
```

Comment: i want to insert into the next empty column not row.